# Two question about Time Travel storage-costs in snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I read the snowflake document a lot. Snowflake will has storage-costs if data update.

"tables-storage-considerations.html" mentioned that:

> As an extreme example, consider a table with rows associated with
> every micro-partition within the table (consisting of 200 GB of
> physical storage). If every row is updated 20 times a day, the table
> would consume the following storage:
>
> Active 200 GB | Time Travel 4 TB | Fail-safe 28 TB | Total Storage 32.2 TB

The first Question is, if a periodical task run 20 times a day, and the task exactly update one row in each micro-partition, then the table still consume 32.2TB for the total storage?

"data-time-travel.html" mentioned that:

> Once the defined period of time has elapsed, the data is moved into
> Snowflake Fail-safe and these actions can no longer be performed.

So my second question is: why Fail-safe cost 28TB, not 24TB (reduce the time travel cost)?

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/data-cdp-storage-costs.html

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/tables-storage-considerations.html

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/data-time-travel.html

Answer (score 1):

First question: yes, it's the fact that the micro-partition is changing that is important not how many rows within it change

Question 2: fail-safe is 7 days of data. 4Tb x 7 = 28Tb

Comment: Thanks a lot.  
Fail-safe period starts immediately after the Time Travel retention period ends.

Comment: Yes "fail-safe" starts after "Time-travel" completes, and thus churn can really start to add up if you have 90 days of Fail-safe. Also given the fact you cannot access that fail-safe that is some very expensive backups. When clones can cost a lot less. But generally Compute is still 5+ times more of the bill. In my prior company we were paying for ~80TB of data, (180TB of total billing) which was coisting ~6K USD a month, and our compute bill was 10x that.. so it is not free, but also not the lowest hanging fruit.